# Mysql update between two timestamps

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table with Name, Number and timestamp. There was a period of time where the data was incorrect (a few weeks).  I want to be able to update the Number field during this period with a scaling difference between last know good dates. How can I write this Update?
For instance,

NAME|Number| datestamp

red, 201, 2017-01-10 12:30:12

red, 205, 2017-01-10 13:30:12   << **good**

red, 1331, 2017-01-10 14:30:12 (bad)

red, 111, 2017-01-10 15:30:12  (bad)

red, 11101, 2017-01-10 16:30:12(bad)

red, 2021, 2017-01-10 17:30:12 (bad)

red, 231, 2017-01-10 18:30:12  << **good**

red, 248, 2017-01-10 19:30:12

How can I write an UPDATE to "smooth out" the numbers between the good rows?

Comment: How do you know what is a *good* row and a *bad* row...

Comment: Also, does your table have a ID(unique) column that you didn't show?

Comment: unfortunately, it does not.

Comment: there is a range of "Bad" rows. I want to UPDATE or the Number value with something like sliding average on rows between the two dates. I marked the bad rows between the good ones in the example above....

Comment: You can certainly update between your good date, and bad data, but I don't completely know what you mean with `sliding average on rows`.

Comment: can you help us with the logic to identify good and bad rows?

Comment: It appears that he knows the good and bad dates and these are fixed. All he needs is to go from 205 just before the first bad sample to 231 after the last bad sample in even steps (e.g. 210, 215, 220, 225)

Comment: Normally the data has slow incremental growth. Because this data is used for a charts, other people querying it will see large spikes in value easily.. We just want to show a "artificial" increase where there was bad data for a period of time.